# Unable to control 'font-size' on mobile device

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size

I'm developing a site that renders all right on the desktop, on all media breakpoint and on DevTool's responsive mobile previews. But when I double check on two mobile phone (a Samsung and a Huawei, using Google Chrome 113.0.5672.76), **some `<p>`s are scaled larger and others are not.** This happens according to the 'Text Size' system setting of the devices: 'normal' will render text in the expected sizes, whereas 'huge' will scale only selected parts of the page, thus ruining the consistent design. I'm trying to either have nothing scaled or everything. Since I've set media queries adjusting `font-size` properly to different screen sizes, I'd prefer to stay in control. On the other hand, if a sight handicaped person whats to view everything bigger - why not. But I need it consistently.

This part of the page gets scaled on mobile devices:

```
<html><body><div><section><div> <div><div><div><p>TEXT
```

The corresponding relevant CSS settings:

```
html { font-size: 62.5% } /* default browser font size = 16px => 10px */
body { 2rem } /* =20px */
```

Everything else down the DOM tree is just `inherit`ed or `em`. On many elements there are various media queries changing `font-size` to appropriate `em` values.

Now the following path on the same page does NOT scale with the phone settings:

```
<html><body><div><section><div> <p>TEXT
```

I read about auto text sizing on some mobiles and thus added the following CSS:

```
* {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

To inhibit scaling, I've also added HTML/CSS with a very high specificity:

```
<html id=htmlId class=htmlClass>
<body id=bodyId class=bodyClass>
```

and for the specific first `<p>` node, that gets scaled:

```
<p id=pId class=pClass style='font-size: 20px !important'>
```

and this CSS at the end of the stylesheet:

```
html, #htmlId, .htmlClass { font-size: 10px !important }

html >body >div section >div >div >div div p[id='pId'],
p#pId, p.pClass, #bodyId, .bodyClass { 
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

(I guess my dispair is obvious at this point.)

This didn't change the rendering in any way. Still the first `<p>` is scaled.

What can I do to have a consistent scaling?

Comment: can you try to create a snippet in your question so we can see the problem in action?

Comment: I might have run into an old Chrome bug, if this applies to my problem. So I'd need a workarround. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=779409